# The recent saves of my html code won't appear

Tags: html, web

The first save of my code keeps appearing but not my recent ones. I don't know what's going on; my code seems to be correct. This is my first website, but I've coded a game before, and this never happened, so I'm confused about what to do.

Here's my code:

```
    <html>

<head>
    <title> CSS width, height, and overflow</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #offical-info {

            background: rgb(206, 200, 200);
            width: 70%;
            height: 180px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;

        }

        #dog1 {
            width: 120px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1> All About Dogs</h1>

    <h3> Why I Love Dogs</h3>

    <ul>
        <li> Energetic
        <li> Fun
        <li> Adorable
    </ul>

    <div id="official-info">
        <h3>Official Info on Dogs</h3>

            <p><img id="dog1" src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=980:*">
            The domestic dog (Canis familiaris or Canis Lupis Familiaris) The dog descended from an
            ancient, extinct wolf, with the modern grey wolf being the dog's nearest living relative.
            The dog was the first species to be domesticated by hunter-gatherers over 15,000 years ago, before the development of agriculture. Their long association with humans has led dogs to be uniquely attuned to human
            behaviour, enabling an abundant cosmopolitan distribution and the ability to thrive on a starch-rich diet
            that would be inadequate for other canids </p>

            <p>The dog has been selectively bred over millennia for various behaviours, sensory capabilities and physical attributes. Dogs are subclassified into breeds, which vary widely in shape, size and color. They perform many roles for humans, such as hunting, herding, pulling loads, protection, assisting police and the military, companionship, therapy, and aiding disabled people. This influence on human society has given them
            the sobriquet of "man's best friend."</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If changes made to the code aren't being reflected then the code itself probably isn't where you'd look for the problem.  How are you viewing the page?  Do you have the local file open in the browser?  If so, are you sure you're saving to the right file?  Or are you viewing it on a server (local or remote)?  If so, are you sure you've updated the server with your changes?  Do the browser or server have a cached version?  We don't know anything about your process for saving and testing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your ID selector  `offical-info` is not the same as the one on your div`<div id="official-info">`